# How to select input device for iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, core-audio

On Mac, I know how to query and select input devices 
first query for number of devices:

```
AudioDeviceID deviceList[ nDevices ];
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof( AudioDeviceID ) * nDevices;
AudioObjectPropertyAddress property = { kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices,
    kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster };
OSStatus result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData( kAudioObjectSystemObject, &property, 0, NULL, &dataSize, (void *) &deviceList );
```

then iterate through the number of devices and query to see if there are input devices among them using:

```
AudioDeviceID id = deviceList[d];
property.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyStreamConfiguration;
property.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeInput;
dataSize = 0;
result = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize( id, &property, 0, NULL, &dataSize );
```

finally get more device info like manufacturer:

```
CFStringRef cfName;
dataSize = sizeof( CFStringRef );
property.mSelector = kAudioObjectPropertyManufacturer;
result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData( id, &property, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &cfName );
```

None of these queries compile with iOS simulator (Xcode5, iOS7 SDK) and I can't seem to find equivalent feature for the iOS simulator (essentially OS X) in the iOS SDK docset.

Is it that we need to follow another procedure or set of APIs?
If so, where can I find instructions?

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the iOS simulator. This is a difference between iOS and OSX.

Comment: Understood. But I suppose when working with the simulator the backend was all running on OS X (the dev desktop) using CoreAudio, no? I would expect some similar device management API, but can't seem to find the docs.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS (7 and later), the AVAudioSession API is used to enumerate and select audio end-points.  The iOS Simulator audio end-points may or may not be connected up to more than one Mac audio end-point thru the Simulator abstraction layer.